# Android: Dialog doesn't pop up

Tags: android, dialog

I am trying to create a simple note app where you can add your favorite store and take some notes which will be stored into a database. When you want to delete the store a dialog should popup which ask you if you really want to delete this particular store when you click on the "OK" button. Otherwise the dialog closes and nothing should happen.

My problem is the dialog doesn't show up.

Here is the code from the particular methode:

```
 public void onDeleteButtonClick(View view) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle(R.string.dlg_confirm);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dlg_confirm_msg);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dlg_btn_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = _helper.getWritableDatabase();
            DataAccess.delete(db, _idNo);
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dlg_btn_ng, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });

    finish();
}
```

I am pretty new at Android and I kinda stuck for hours.

Thank you in advance

Comment: AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `builder.show()` to show dialog.

Comment: Thank you, now the dialog pops up, but the window disappears instantly. Is my code garbage or is the position of the call wrong?